# How to read Apache Flink data from CosmosDB

Tags: apache-flink, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Apache Flink and I'd like to read data from CosmosDB and create a source.
However, there's no standard connector for Cosmos, so how can I read this data?

Do I need to create a custom source connector (not sure how to do this)? Or could I read it with table API Connectors (JDBC or something)?